# What can I do to address diminishing logical operators?

Tags: javascript, object, logical-operators

I have an object like

```
{
  a: 'string1',
  b: 'string2',
  c: 'string3',
  d: 'string4',
  e: 'string5',
  f: 'string6',
  g: 'string7',
  h: 'string8',
  i: 'string9'
}
```

and I need to do the following logic

```
if (a && (b || c || d || e || f || g || h || i)) dothis1()
if (b && (c || d || e || f || g || h || i)) dothis2()
if (c && (d || e || f || g || h || i)) dothis3()
if (d && (e || f || g || h || i)) dothis4()
if (e && (f || g || h || i)) dothis5()
if (f && (g || h || i)) dothis6()
if (g && (h || i)) dothis6()
if (h && i) dothis7()
```

I have tried it the above way but there has to be a simpler way to do this that's blowing over me. Does anyone have any better options?

Comment: Put all the values into one array, the functions to call into a second parallel array, and take a stab at writing some array-based logic. If you get stuck, show is your attempt and we can advise you further.

Comment: Then I'm still in the same pattern am I not? If I put all the values into an array and try an `array.includes` it's still going to be `if (a && (array.includes(string2) || array.includes(string3)...` etc. I think it's not a matter of what I use, it's that I don't understand the how since it's kinda funky. Which array method would you suggest I look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do this with an array. The function number is a little tricky - try placing all the functions into an array as well. And use `some` to short-circuit the loop:

```
const funcArr = [dothis1, dothis2, dothis3, dothis4, dothis5, dothis6, dothis7];

Object.entries(obj).some((e, i, a) => {
  if (i + 2 == a.length && e && a[i + 1]) return (funcArr[funcArr.length - 1](), 1);
  if (e && a.slice(i + 1).some(e => e)) return (funcArr[i](), 1);
});
```